# Watson Unity SDK speech-to-text after build on android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, speech-to-text, watson

Hello I'm use Watson Unity SDK for my project.

I use Speech to Text service for 2 languages English and Chinese.

On Windows and Unity Editor it works perfect!

But after build on Android Watson only text my speech only in English.

I tested using TestSpeechToText.cs change Language in Inspector and also code in language variables.

But still now work on Android Devices. Please help me.

I don't know why this is happen.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working on an android device. Please ensure that the device has access to internet (mine didn't and it was causing me a lot of issues).

Open the **scene** `TestSpeechToText` and find the `SpeechToTextWidget`. In the inspector, change the value of `Language` to `zh-CN`.

Open the `Build Settings` menu and select all eight scenes to build in the Android platform. On your Android device select `Test Speech To Text` and speak in Chinese.

You will not be able to speak in English and Chinese without changing the language model in the SpeechToTextWidget between `en-US` and `zh-CN`.